# HTML flash file submit to email

Tags: html, email, flash

I have a Flash .SWF file in an HTML page that you can fill out and I need to be able to send it to an email address after you fill it out. I have searched for answers and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have not found an answer because web browsers don't send emails. You need to pass the form information to a server that will do that for you.

Comment: i have one but what I'm trying to say is i can't attach the file to the email

Comment: You can't attach a file. File uploads need to be initiated by the user, using <input type="file">. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823097/passing-file-paths-from-flash-to-javascript-for-upload